# Vitest React - component not "re-rendering" after server request

Tags: reactjs, testing-library, vitest

This is my simplifiedReact component:

```
export const EntryDetail = () => {
  const { articleId } = useParams();
  const [article, setArticle] = useState({ title: null, body: null, comments: [], likes: [] });
  const { title, body, comments, likes } = article;

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const response = await getArticleDetail(articleId);
        const { title, body, comments, likes } = response.data;
        setArticle({ title, body, comments, likes });
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Container>
      {
        !article.title
          ? <div>Loading...</div>
          : <>
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            <p className="body">{body}</p>
          </>
      }

    </Container>
  );
};
```

And this is my test:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { StateProvider } from '../../config/state';
import { EntryDetail } from './index';

const flushPromises = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0));

vi.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  useParams: () => ({
    articleId: '63d466ca3d00b50db15aed93',
  }),
}));

describe("EntryDetail component", () => {
  it("should render the EntryDetail component correctly", async () => {
    render(
      <EntryDetail />
    );
    await flushPromises();
    const element = screen.getByRole("heading");
    expect(element).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

This is what I'm getting in the console:
[image]

I was expecting the "await flushPromises()" would actually wait for the response from the call in the useEffect to the "update" the component", but I guess this is kind of "static"? How should this be handled? I actually want to test if the component itself works effectively, I don't want to mock a response, I want to see if the component actually reacts appropriately after the response is back.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the example in https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/tree/main/examples/react-testing-lib exactly. Make sure you're not missing config in `vite.config.js` or in `setup.ts`.

Answer (score 0):

you can update as per below example of your **simplifiedReact** component:

```
export const EntryDetail = () => {
  const { articleId } = useParams();
  const [article, setArticle] = useState({ title: null, body: null, comments: [], likes: [] });

  useEffect(() => {
    const getArticle = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await getArticleDetail(articleId);
        const { title, body, comments, likes } = response.data;
        setArticle({ title, body, comments, likes });
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    };

    getArticle();
  }, [articleId]);

  return (
    <Container>
      {!article.title ? (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      ) : (
        <>
          <h1>{article.title}</h1>
          <p className="body">{article.body}</p>
        </>
      )}
    </Container>
  );
};


import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { StateProvider } from '../../config/state';
import { EntryDetail } from './index';

const flushPromises = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0));

vi.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  useParams: () => ({
    articleId: '63d466ca3d00b50db15aed93',
  }),
}));

describe("EntryDetail component", () => {
  it("should render the EntryDetail component correctly", async () => {
    render(
      <EntryDetail key={articleId} />
    );
    await flushPromises();
    const element = screen.getByRole("heading");
    expect(element).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are working with async renders, I use the `waitFor` react testing library function. Try changing the code to this:

```
import { StateProvider } from '../../config/state';
import { EntryDetail } from './index';

vi.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  useParams: () => ({
    articleId: '63d466ca3d00b50db15aed93',
  }),
}));

describe("EntryDetail component", () => {
  it("should render the EntryDetail component correctly", async () => {
    render(
      <EntryDetail />
    );
    const element = await waitFor(() => screen.getByRole("heading"));
    expect(element).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

If you get a warning about needing async changes to be wrapped in `act`, then follow Zakaria's advice about wrapping the render in `act`.